# How do I render a label in extjs?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I would like to render my label. Something very simple like below :

```
xtype: 'label',  
text: 'Hi There',
renderer :  function(val) {
    return '<b>' + val + '</b>';
},
```

I would ***not*** like to use a **cls** and a **CSS** file because I think that is overkill for what I am doing.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use html instead of text.

Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/mjq

```
{
    xtype : "label",
    html : "<b>bold</b><i>italic</i>"
}
```